# GPU ATI Radeon Sapphire HD 6850

Tags: software-installation

Good evening. Put your system for the first time, what driver to put for the video card ATI Radeon Sapphire HD 6850? Thank you!

Comment: Linux comes with opensource drivers for that card. I have had the best luck with AMD cards running on the opensource driver. I suggest you keep it and not try to install the driver from the AMD website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your card is already supported by the open source drivers included in Elementary OS.

To install updated drivers for all hardware run the following command in a terminal and reboot your system once it completes, [reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack):

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`

To get the latest stable graphics drivers (for better performance and compatibility with newer games) you can add [this PPA](http://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/updates) to your system.